# How to upload a file from local to S3 bucket using EC2 linux machine?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

How can I upload a file from my local system to **AWS S3 bucket** using **EC2 Linux machine**? How can I use `aws s3 cp` command here?

I've tried `aws s3 cp <fileName> s3://<BucketName>`, but the above command works if the file is in the linux machine.

Comment: Your question is very confusing. If you want to upload from your local system to aws s3 bucket: Install awscli in your local and run the same command

Comment: Hi @AshBlake I wanted to upload files from my local machine to aws s3 bucket. This process I need to do it from my EC2 machine using aws command, so I couldn't find any suitable command for the same.

Comment: The EC2 instance does not have access to your local machine (at least that is VERY unlikely). Either upload from your local machine directly to S3 or upload from local to EC2, e.g. via SCP and *then* upload from EC2 to S3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like 2 steps are required here.

1. Transfer files from your local drive to the EC2 instance.

- You can transfer the files with something like SCP, S3 isn't in the picture here.

2. Upload the files from EC2 to S3.

- You can use the cli here, similar to the command you already posted.

On which step are you stuck here exactly?

Comment: Thank you, I was looking to directly take from local and upload it to S3, but got to know that it's not required and will be following the above steps.

Comment: That would also work - you could upload directly to S3 from your local drive.

Comment: Yeah but I wanted to upload by giving commands using Ec2 instance.